# Marquee, change content dynamically and restart scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, marquee

I have a `marquee` on my website:

```
<marquee>Hello! <span id="text">Welcome to my website.</span></marquee>
```

I want to change dynamically the content of the span with `id="text"` from `marquee`:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "This is my website. Happy reading!";
}, 5000);
```

```html
<marquee>Hello! <span id="text">Welcome to my website.</span>
</marquee>
```

All works well. The problem is that I want to restart the marquee, from the beginning after changing the text. Imagine first text is a longer one, when changing with another, it will not be entirely readable at first scroll; the visitor will see it from middle.

So, I want to restart the marquee scroll from beginning.

Comment: imho -> [What are arguments against the usage of a ticker / marquee on websites?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76951/what-are-arguments-against-the-usage-of-a-ticker-marquee-on-websites)

Comment: @Andreas I just developed a HTML5 TV System. A TV channel is usually using a ticker. That's why I am asking the question. Moreover, I am in agree with your post. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not what you want or expect. But this should restart the marquee.
I would delete and reinsert the marquee in the DOM with a new element.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("marquee").innerHTML = '<marquee>Hello! <span id="text">This is my website. Happy reading!</span></marquee>';
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div id="marquee">
<marquee>Hello! <span id="text">Welcome to my website.</span>
</marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it is the best solution, even if I must rewrite the entire marquee content (not changing only a part of marquee as I asked).

Answer (score 1):

Select your marquee and use .start() to restart it.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "This is my website. Happy reading!";
  document.getElementsByTagName("marquee")[0].start();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<marquee>Hello! <span id="text">Welcome to my website.</span>
</marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a library to help with this:

Vanilla JS: https://github.com/tjenkinson/dynamic-marquee

React: https://github.com/tjenkinson/dynamic-marquee-react